# Link with slash to div

Tags: javascript, .htaccess

Is there anyway to do a link for example /gallery which is a div inside the main page without having to go the link but to the div itself and on reload, not to show a 404 page but to go to the main page and to the div?

Answer (score 1):

You have to set an id for the div element, then you can refer to it from a link with hashtag (#)

I will show you a little example here:

```
<-- in your html file-->
<div id="scrollHere">Div's content</div>
```

then you can refer to if from url:

```
http://yourdomain.com/some-uri#scrollHere
```

The browser will automatically scroll to the scrollHere div

Comment: I know that, however, I've been looking not to use the link as #div but as /div

Comment: Then you should do some hacky jquery stuff :D checking on the url and scrolling to that div

Answer (score 1):

Get the url and retrive all after last "/".
Get the element you wish to scroll to.
Use scrollIntoView on selected element

```js
var url = "http://mywebsite/folder/green";
var array = url.split('/');
var lastsegment = array[array.length-1];
var elmnt = document.getElementById(lastsegment);
elmnt.scrollIntoView();
```

```css
div{
  height: 400px;
  width: 100%;
}
#blue{
  background-color: blue;
}
#red{
  background-color: red;
}
#green{
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div id="blue"></div>
<div id="red"></div>
<div id="green"></div>
```

Comment: I know that, however, I've been looking not to use the link as #div but as /div

Comment: @ChrisChong Okey changed my code to what you asked :)